# jQuery and WCF service problem

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, wcf

I am creating an application that uses jQuery to make ajax calls to ASP.NET WCF Web Service. Everything works fine most of the time but eventually (about twice per week) the service stops working with the error below. The only solution is to clear the ASP.NET Temporary Files. The problem seems to start by the time the application pool recycles but not on each recycle. Please help as I'm trying to figure this out for weeks now!

> WebHost failed to process a request.
>   Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/6957828
>   Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException:
>   The service '/Chat2/Chat.svc' cannot
>   be activated due to an exception
>   during compilation.  The exception
>   message is: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'App_Web_vpupi5wr,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'App_Web_vpupi5wr, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

Comment: The guy here seems to have the same problem but no resolution: http://forums-silverlight-dit.neudesic.com/forums/p/102577/247707.aspx

Comment: Is this a dynamically compiled site? And in IIS are there other applications in the same app pool?

Comment: It is a precompiled site. Yes, there are other application on the pool but they are not currently running.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the service/webapp in debug mode?  If so, can you set the compilation element in your web.config to false?

```
<compilation debug='false'/>
```

The KB article that HurnsMobile linked to also mentions setting the batch attribute to false also.

```
<compilation debug='false' batch='false'/>
```

Also, if you could provide additional information about your environment (.NET version, IIS version, O/S, etc.), that would be helpful, too.

Comment: Yes, I am running in debug mode. I will try setting debug and batch to false and see if it will help. Environment is .NET 4.0 and Windows 7 with IIS 7 as well as Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 (problems happen on both).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to open a ticket with Microsoft for an exact answer but they will probably send you the following hotfix - http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;934839

Comment: I will try opening a ticket. The hotfix seems to be for the same problem but it is for .NET 2.0 while I'm using .NET 4.0